# Open a new window after 3 seconds in same tab

Tags: javascript

Hii this is my second question i will try to explain. This is a code which close the window after 3 seconds i want new window english.html should appear. thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loaded()
{

window.setTimeout(CloseMe, 3000);
}

function CloseMe() 
{
  window.close();
 }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="loaded()">
Hello!
</body>
```

Comment: `function CloseMe(){ location = 'yourNewPage.php' }`. Just change `yourNewPage.php` to the page you want to open.

Answer (score 2):

You can't open a new window in response to anything other than a user interaction. "Three seconds after the page has loaded" is not a user interaction so will be blocked by the standard popup blocking rules that all modern browsers are required to implement by the HTML specification.

Try redirecting the user instead, or better yet, don't: Skip the three second page entirely. If something is worth showing to the user, then it is worth showing to the user until they click a link. That way you know they weren't giving their attention to another tab while your content waltzed by unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple example of how to achieve what you want:

```js
//<![CDATA[
// external.js
var doc, bod, htm, C, E, T; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){ // load start

// I threw in a few goodies to study - it will help you later
doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
C = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
T = function(tag){ // returns an Array of Elements by tag name
  return doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
}
// notice that `window` is implicit, so you don't actually need to use it to access its properties
setTimeout(function(){ // unexecuted functions and Anonymous functions behave the same
  location = 'https://www.w3.org'; // it's really this easy to set the `window.location.href`
}, 3000);

});// load end
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div>Just a very simple example</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** You should practice using external sources so they can be cached. Just make sure you change the filename and path to any source you later change.